# Issues with RoR Mysql deployment in Open shift

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, openshift

I am trying to deploy a simple RoR in openshift.I am using Ruby-1.9 and mysql-5.1 , the app works fine with local deployment and it is not working in openshift.Previously i had the same issue and there was an open bug with passenger fusion in openshift has any one fixed this or is this still an issue.If there is any work around please do let me know.
I am posting my database yml config in here.

```
mysql: &mysql
adapter: mysql2
database: "<%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME']%>"
username: "<%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME']%>"
password: "<%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD']%>"
host:     <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST']%>
port:     <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT']%>
enter code here
```

my rhc tail  output is as follows

```
==> app-root/logs/ruby.log <==
10.80.227.1 - - [03/Jun/2014:01:11:48 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Ruby"
10.80.227.1 - - [03/Jun/2014:01:11:48 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Ruby"
10.80.227.1 - - [03/Jun/2014:02:11:28 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Ruby"
10.80.227.1 - - [03/Jun/2014:02:11:28 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Ruby"
10.80.227.1 - - [03/Jun/2014:03:11:37 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Ruby"
10.80.227.1 - - [03/Jun/2014:03:11:37 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Ruby"
10.80.227.1 - - [03/Jun/2014:04:13:34 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Ruby"
10.80.227.1 - - [03/Jun/2014:04:13:34 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Ruby"
==> app-root/logs/mysql.log <==

    140602 21:52:59 mysqld_safe Logging to        '/var/lib/openshift/538ce6295973caef290000fd/mysql//stdout.err'.
140602 21:52:59 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/openshift/538ce6295973caef290000fd/mysql/data/
140602 21:52:59 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/openshift/538ce6295973caef290000fd/mysql/data/
140602 21:52:59  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 32.0M
140602 21:52:59  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140602 21:53:00  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
140602 21:53:01 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140602 21:53:01 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/var/lib/openshift/538ce6295973caef290000fd/mysql//socket/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

For testing purposes i have a welcome controller and index page in rails that works fine with local machine.
Can any one please point me to the right resource or help it would be great help for me.

Comment: Why are you using mysql: &mysql in database.yml file ??

Answer (score 1):

You have `mysql: &mysql` in your database.yml file. Try this

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME']%>
  pool: 30
  timeout: 30000
  checkout_timeout: 30000
  host: <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST']%>
  port: <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT']%>
  username: <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME']%>
  password: <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD']%>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestions.
I have followed your suggestion and removed the mysql: &mysql
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get 'welcome/index'
       root 'welcome#index'
this is  my routes.rb which shows clearly i have a welcome controller and an index view still am redirected to the default openshift page.My application link is as follows
http://testing-bl0g.rhcloud.com/
I have even tried with the view in the URL as follows
http://testing-bl0g.rhcloud.com/index 
Is there any thing am missing still.thanks for your time and help.